# CakePHP 2.5.1 Number helper does not show currency symbol 'after'

Tags: php, cakephp, number-formatting, cakephp-2.5

I tried to set up a number format for living space in Cakephp, it should look like this: "100,00 m²"
As I use this format often, I want to create a default format in my AppController beforeFilter():

```
CakeNumber::addFormat('AREA', array(
    'thousands' => ' ', 
    'decimals' => ',', 
    'places' => 2, 
    'before' => false, 
    'after' => ' m²'
));
```

In my view file I call:
`echo $this->Number->currency($area, 'AREA');`

The problem: 'after' does not apply, so it is missing "m²", only "100,00" shows up.

I know living space is not a currency, but it looks like the best option to define reusable number format.

Edit solution:
Thanks to Mantas:

```
CakeNumber::addFormat('AREA', array('thousands' => ' ', 
  'decimals' => ',', 
  'places' => 2, 
  'wholeSymbol' => ' m²', 
  'wholePosition' => 'after'
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set 

`[
    'wholeSymbol' => ' m²',
    'wholePosition' => 'after',
]`

to achieve desired format.